# Replicate iPhone camera tap to brighten / focus in AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

So I notice when it's dark and you press on the screen in the iPhones camera app it focus' and brightens than area.

I think I got the focus part down:

```
        if (captureDevice?.lockForConfiguration(nil) == true) {
        self.captureDevice?.focusPointOfInterest = CGPointMake(focus_x, focus_y)
       }
```

However, how do I get it to make that part brighter? It does not seem like it's done through lowlightboost since that is not supported on my phone (5S). It's also not using flash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the `focusPointOfInterest` property you are already using, there is also an [`exposurePointOfInterest`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/exposurePointOfInterest) property that should help you achieve the functionality you're looking for.